# How do I add output of azure cli command to github actions

Tags: github, github-actions, azure-cli

I have a github action where I am logging in to my azure account and I want to add output of azure cli command to github action variable. How do I do this?

This is my github action job

```
jobs:
    StagingBuildAndDeploy:
     name: Build and Deploy
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@master
     - name: 'Login via Azure CLI'
       uses: azure/login@v1
       with:
         creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }
```

Now I want add output of this command to a variable

```
az acr repository show-tags --name acrname --repository reponame --orderby time_desc --top 1
```

This command would fetch me the latest image in acr. How do I add that image name to a github action variable

I tried doing this

```
- name: Read image_name
       id: getimagename
       run: echo "::set-output name=image_name::$(az acr repository show-tags --name acrname --repository reponame --orderby time_desc --top 1)"
```

and then I tried accessing it by this ${{ steps.getimagename.outputs.image_name }}

This is what I was getting as output when I am assigning the value to variable

```
Run h=$(az acr repository show-tags --name acrname --repository *** --orderby time_desc --top 1)
  "tag132"
]
```

This is what I got when I printed my variable

```
Run echo "["
[
```

Comment: Does the output of `az` go to stderr perhaps? If you append `2>&1` to the command, is the variable still empty?

Comment: I have edited the question. I wasn't getting empty value but this "[".

Comment: Can you show how exactly you're accessing the output, in YAML? Have you tried enabling debugging (add a repo secret `ACTIONS_RUNNER_DEBUG` with value `true`, see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/enabling-debug-logging))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a test with this:

```yaml
jobs:
  test-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout this repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2

      - name: Test1
        id: test1
        run: |
          h=$(az --version)

          echo "::set-output name=h::$h"

      - name: Test2
        run: |
          echo "${{ steps.test1.outputs.h }}"
```

and it works:
[image]

Below query

```
az acr repository show-tags --name acrname --repository *** --orderby time_desc --top 1
```

produces output as follows:

```
[
  "SomeValue"
]
```

But if you add `-o tsv`

```
az acr repository show-tags --name acrname --repository *** --orderby time_desc --top 1 -o tsv
```

then you will get just value:

```
SomeValue
```

Comment: I tried this. For that specific azure cli command I am getting "[" in my variable.

Comment: You need to save it in variable nad parse it or try to add `-o table`.

Comment: @AnshulWalia please check my edit.